# How to visualize the resulting state vector using CVNeuralNetLayers and Lightning qubit device

Tags: quantum-state, pennylane

I'm trying to learn how to use PennyLane's CVNeuralNetLayers. I wrote this code below but I am not able to use the resulting state of the circuit generated by this layer. I looked for examples in the documentation but found nothing.

I already tried to change the device to "default.qubit" but a similar error occurs. Is it possible to visualize the resulting state of this layer? Should i change the pennylane device?

```
from pennylane.templates.layers import CVNeuralNetLayers
from pennylane import numpy as np
import pennylane as qml

dev = qml.device('lightning.qubit', wires=4)

n_layers = 1
n_wires = 4

shapes = CVNeuralNetLayers.shape(n_layers, n_wires)
weights = [np.random.random(shape) for shape in shapes]

@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(weights):
  CVNeuralNetLayers(*weights, wires=[0, 1, 2, 3])
  return qml.state()

print("\n\n", qml.draw(circuit, expansion_strategy="lightning")(weights))

ket = circuit(weights)
print("\nResulting State: ", ket)
```

The output is:

```
DeviceError: Gate Beamsplitter not supported on device lightning.qubit
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CVNeuralNetLayers` use a very particular set of quantum gates that are unique to photonics. The only device that is available in PennyLane which can simulate these gates is the [Strawberry Fields plugin device](https://docs.pennylane.ai/projects/strawberryfields/en/latest/). It should be able to handle circuits with `CVNeuralNetLayers`.

As a secondary note, this plugin is not as feature-rich as some other ones, so I'm not 100% whether or not it will support the functionality you are looking to use (`qml.draw` and `qml.state`). You'll have to check whether it suits your particular needs.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly my problem.
I searched in the strawberry fields documentation and unfortunately I didn't find any device from this plugin that supports the qml.state or qml.draw functions